# Firefox doesn't open popups on all sites even after manually clicking on the button

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, browser

I am using standard Firefox (currently version 108.0.1 64-bit) on Macbook Air M1. After a while of having the window open, popups stop showing up. This includes attachment popups or download popups, which prevents me from doing what I need to do. I need to restart for it to work.

I have deactivated all add-ons and tried again.

How can I fix this? It is annoying that I have to restart my browser for this.

UPDATE: This is happening to all my browsers (Chrome & Brave) when I have multiple tabs open for a few days. So it might be something on the OS level.

Comment: It could be your Security Software that's blocking popups. Test also running `firefox -safe-mode`.

Comment: OP: I noticed it started happening to my Brave as well. It happens after a few days of having windows open. So something is up with permissions on OS level maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Not a definite answer, but a place to look:

- In the URL (location) bar, enter `about:config`.
- Accept the warning to proceed with caution (I miss the old Mozillasaurus pic).
- In the *Search* box on that page, enter `popup`.

There are a number of popup settings, e.g., *apz.popups.enabled*, *dom.block_multiple_popups* and *dom.popup_maximum*. The last, in particular, had a default limit of *20* on this machine, and perhaps increasing that could help. One reason for imposing a limit were pernicious sites that spewed popups in an endless loop to make it difficult to shut the browser.

You might need to experiment -- and if you *do* find the culprit ***please*** post a comment on what works, so this can be made a true *answer*. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out this is not Firefox specific. I tried this solution and couldn't fix the problem.